# Using custom font with Gzip and @font-face

Tags: fonts, gzip, font-face

I'm trying to use custom font using the @font-face property, and I'm also trying to save some space by putting custom font in gzip archive, so I was thinking can font-face work with fonts that are in gzip archive?

I've found a way how to do so, but I'm doubting that it's working.
http://www.phpied.com/gzip-your-font-face-files/

Anyhow, by following the tips from the link above I've come up with this code, and like I said, I doubt it works, so can someone help me out with it?

```
#content h1{
font:64px gzipper;
color:#fff;
}
@font-face {
font-family: gzipper;
src: local('gzipper.gz'),
     url('BRLNSR.TTF') format('truetype');
}
```

Custom font is loaded and displayed properly, but I when I remove the unzipped font from my root folder the custom font doesn't loads.
I'm currently testing this on my computer, so there are no server issues with gzip files.

Answer (score 0):

Those fonts are gzipped on the fly, so putting gzip archives on your server don't make much sense.
What happens is you need to put just regular files and setup your server to dinamically compress them.
Think mod_deflate in apache etc.